# Firebase event to listen duplicate data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any event to listen data on every update whether it is exactly the same data or not?

Let me explain what I want to achieve.

If I set the data as shown below on every 1 second interval

#### Write Data

```
setInterval(() => {
  firebaseRef.child('liveUser').set({ userId: 1});
}, 1000);
```

How can I listen liveUser on every update? Right now with my current implementation firebase stop `.on('value')` event if the value is duplicate.

#### Read Data

```
firebaseRef.child('liveUser').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

I am aware of alternative solution of using timestamp with liveUser object, but it would be helpful if firebase already provides solution for duplicate data.

Comment: By design, a listener is only called when data is changed. Writing identical data to the same location does not change the data and thus doesn't fire the listener. As you suggest, you could update a timestamp (or random) value under the node to force the listener to trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, a listener is only called when data is changed. Writing identical data to the same location does not change the data and thus doesn't trigger attached listeners.

To trigger attached listeners, you need to make a change to the node:

```
setInterval(() => {
  firebaseRef.child('liveUser').set({
    userId: 1,
    timestamp: Math.floor(Date.now())
  });
}, 1000);
```